# Why I don't do this regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem about a regular expression... Python can do the next part of code but if I change the final expression I can't run the code.

In the final line

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = 'http://www.ebay.es/itm/IMN-DE-NEVERA-DE-LA-CERVEZA-BUDWEISER-/281134822561'    #raw_input('Dime la url que deseas: ')    
code = urllib2.urlopen(url).read();
soup = BeautifulSoup(code)
tag = soup.find('span', {'class' : "vi-is1-t"}).contents[0]
print tag
print re.search('[\d*]+:[\d*]+:\d*' , tag).group() #If I put '[\d*]+:[\d*]+:[\d*]' not run
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change the expression if it works? What's your goal in changing the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any characters **inside** a `[...]` character class are part of that class:

```
[\d*]
```

matches either a digit *or* a literal `*` asterisk. If you wanted to match 0 or more digits, put the asterisk **outside** the class:

```
[\d]*
```

at which point you don't need to use `[..]` as the `\d` is a class all by itself:

```
\d*
```

The first two patterns *already* use `+` (1 or more), so those match 1 or more digits *or* asterisks.

What you wanted to match then is:

```
print re.search('\d+:\d+:\d+' , tag).group()
```

or even:

```
print re.search('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}' , tag).group()
```

to match just 2 digits each.